Unable to access Eclipse Marketplace in Mac M1
I have installed eclipse Kepler in Mac M1 and I'm unable to connect to eclipse marketplace. Below is the error message,
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed.This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry

Below are the options that I have tried however none of them work,

Google.com is opening in the Internet explorer from eclipse.
Changed the network connection from direct to manual/native.
Disabled firewall for eclipse to allow external connections.
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true line added after -vmargs in the eclipse.ini file
Tried to launch eclipse as an administrator using sudo command

I have ran out of options now.
Error Message
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content.xml.
Log Details
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa,     NL=en_CAjavax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not     authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)


What do you mean by "eclipse Keeper"? Eclipse Kepler? But Eclipse Kepler is more than a decade and 28 releases behind? That cannot be true. Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

@howlger this is Eclipse Kepler. I have added the log details

The solution is to use the current Eclipse version. In general, please check that the software you are using is up-to-date before asking.

@howlger This is the correct version and it works without any issues in Windows and causes issue in Mac. This is the eclipse that is supposed to be used for BIRT report development.

If you can't update your Eclipse, try to update your JRE  or update the CA certs within it. It's not the latest maintenance release of 1.7 AFAICT. Otherwise, you will have to move to something newer.

Not true. Of course, the latest Eclipse version is supposed to be used for BIRT development.. Again, you are using outdated software that has been archived years ago. Please take security more seriously and update your Eclipse, BIRT and Java. Nowadays everything is HTTPS only for security reasons.
